# Tensorflow shape inference static RNN compiler error

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I am working on OCR software optimized for phone camera images.

Currently, each 300 x 1000 x 3 (RGB) image is reformatted as a 900 x 1000 numpy array. I have plans for a more complex model architecture, but for now I just want to get a baseline working. I want to get started by training a static RNN on the data that I've generated.

Formally, I am feeding in n_t at each timestep t for T timesteps, where n_t is a 900-vector and T = 1000 (similar to reading the whole image left to right). Here is the Tensorflow code in which I create batches for training:

```
sequence_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(example_generator, (tf.int32, 
tf.int32))
sequence_dataset = sequence_dataset.batch(experiment_params['batch_size'])
iterator = sequence_dataset.make_initializable_iterator() 
x_batch, y_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

The tf.nn.static_bidirectional_rnn documentation claims that the input must be a "length T list of inputs, each a tensor of shape [batch_size, input_size], or a nested tuple of such elements." So, I go through the following steps in order to get the data into the correct format.

```
# Dimensions go from [batch, n , t] -> [t, batch, n]
x_batch = tf.transpose(x_batch, [2, 0, 1])

# Unpack such that x_batch is a length T list with element dims [batch_size, n]
x_batch = tf.unstack(x_batch, experiment_params['example_t'], 0)
```

Without altering the batch any further, I make the following call:

```
output, _, _ = tf.nn.static_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, x_batch, dtype=tf.int32)
```

Note that I do not explicitly tell Tensorflow the dimensions of the matrices (this could be the problem). They all have the same dimensionality, yet I am getting the following bug:

```
ValueError: Input size (dimension 0 of inputs) must be accessible via shape 
inference, but saw value None.
```

At which point in my stack should I be declaring the dimensions of my input? Because I am using a Dataset and hoping to get its batches directly to the RNN, I am not sure that the "placeholder -> feed_dict" route makes sense. If that in fact is the method that makes the most sense, let me know what that looks like (I definitely do not know). Otherwise, let me know if you have any other insights to the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the absence of static shape information is that TensorFlow doesn't understand enough about the `example_generator` function to determine the shapes of the arrays it yields, and so it assumes the shapes can be completely different from one element to the next. The best way to constrain this is to specify the optional `output_shapes` argument to [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), which accepts a nested structure of shapes matching the structure of the yielded elements (and the `output_types` argument).

In this case you'd pass a tuple of two shapes, which can be partially specified. For example, if the `x` elements are `900 x 1000` arrays and the `y` elements are scalars:

```
sequence_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    example_generator, (tf.int32, tf.int32),
    output_shapes=([900, 1000], []))
```